Dell DA200 display resolution
I've read several posts about graphic issues with Dell DA200 USB C dongle, but I have slightly different problem than others.
Setup:

Dell XPS 15 7590
Dell DA200
Dell monitor - can't find the model number - (via VGA port)

Problem: The external monitor works, but with strange behaviour.
Quick comparison test:

On Windows 10 (dual boot) it works up to 1920x1080.
On Ubuntu 22.04 (kernel 6.5.0-28-generic), max is 1024x768 only.

Based on this post, the recommended kernel is v4.13.4, while I'm beyond that already (6.5.0-28). Doesn't this include the fix?
Additional info:

Additional lsusb output once plugged in

Bus 001 Device 008: ID 0835:2a01 Action Star Enterprise Co., Ltd BILLBOARD DEVICE
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub

